# autocomplete= off not working in chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

We are working on one web application in that one payment page is there.

In that we have two Text box one is for Credit Card Number and second one is for Verification Code and it type="Password".

Now problem is when page is load in google-chrome it found type="Password" it load Save email id in Credit Card Textbox and password in Verification Code.

Now try to solve this issue i was try out something like below.

```
<form autocomplete="off">

<asp:textbox autocomplete="off">
```

This above try is not work for me. i was googling it but by luck it's not work for me.

Comment: Could also be client side cache.  Try setting the appropriate expiry headers on the page to prevent Chrome from loading the page from cache/memory.

Comment: If your browser ignores autocomplete="off" adding a random string in place of 'off' will fix the issue.

Eg, autocomplete="autocomplete_off_hack_xfr4!k"

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It appears that Chrome now ignores autocomplete="off" unless it is on the `<form autocomplete="off">` tag since v34.

you can't cheat by create an hidden input over. Auto complete feature will get the first input text to fill data.

**Method 1:**

```
<form id="" method="post" action="" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text" style="display:none" />
    <input type="password" style="display:none">
    <asp:textbox autocomplete="off">
</form>
```

So put this before your textbox.

```
<input type="text" style="display:none" />
```

**Method 2:**

Change

```
autocomplete="off"
```

to

```
autocomplete="false"
```

**Method 3:**
Browser autofill in by readonly-mode.

```
 <input type="password" readonly onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');"/>
```

**Method 4:**

For username password combinations. Chrome heuristics looks for the pattern.

```
<input type="text" onfocus="this.type='password'">
```

**Method 5:**
jQuery

```js
if ($.browser.webkit) {
    $('input[name="password"]').attr('autocomplete', 'off');
    $('input[name="email"]').attr('autocomplete', 'off');
}
```

Comment: Method 3 seems to be the most reliable and standardised across browsers

Comment: None of these methods works on Chrome for me. Version 94.0.4606.71 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Method 1 works for chrome, but I had to add name="username" and name="password" - of course my inputs have a different id of APIUsername/APIPassword - Chrome Version 109.0.5414.75 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 6):

This is the only solution that worked for me with both Autocomplete and Chrome's Autofill:
It works also after calling `new this.props.google.maps.places.Autocomplete`

1. Add autocomplete="off" on the form tag.
2. Set autocomplete="none" directly on the input inside the form and set the attribute again on focus.

   ```
    <form autocomplete="off">
        <input type="text" autocomplete="none" onfocus="this.setAttribute('autocomplete', 'none');"/>
    </form>
   ```

Comment: This worked for me on latest Chrome version

Answer (score 1):

this is works if you want to keep white as your input background color

```
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" readonly onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');" style="background-color: white;">
```

Answer (score 1):

use this solution

```
<input type="password" class="form-control auto-complete-off" id="password" name="password" autocomplete="new-password">
```

Answer (score 1):

Chrome does not support `autocomplete="off"` at the form level for some input fields.
There are 2 solutions to do so:

- In your form, if only two or three fields ignore autocomplete="off", then use the field name itself as the autocomplete value. i.e. autocomplete=

```html
<form:input type="text" id="name" path="name" autocomplete="name"/>
```

- Instead of defining field name manually for each field, use a script for all text typed input at the loading of the page or after.

```js
if ($.browser.chrome) { 
    $(document).on('focus click tap', 'input', function() {
        $(this).attr("autocomplete", 'block');
    });
} else {
    $(document).on('focus click tap', 'input', function() {
        $(this).attr("autocomplete", 'off');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this solution is no longer working in chrome 95 and above,

Try using a normal input with type text, disable copy and pasting then add a style with property -webkit-text-security to add character mask on typing

#Not that this css property is not universal as mentionned here https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-security

Answer (score 0):

This works well and also compatible with MDL (Material Design Light):

```js
// Fix chrome's ignore on autocomplete=off
$('input[autocomplete=off]').each(function(){
    var copy = $(this).clone();
    copy.val('');
    copy.removeAttr('autocomplete');
    copy.insertAfter($(this));
    $(this).hide().removeAttr('required id class');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
automcomplete="off" or automcomplete="false"
```

or Define autocomplete inside Input field

```js
$('input[name="password"]').attr('autocomplete', 'off');//Disable cache
```

Answer (score 0):

very simple, you can follow this

```js
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('[autocomplete="off"]');
elements.forEach(element => {
    element.setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");
    element.style.backgroundColor = "inherit";
    setTimeout(() => {
        element.removeAttribute("readonly");
    }, 500);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it not possible to use password type where text type is required?Regardless of the method presented above, Chrome unconditionally handles autocomplete if the name is the same.
So, I used a method to randomly change the name like this.

```js
$(document).on('focus click tap'
    , 'input[autocomplete][autocomplete!=""]:not([data-oname][data-oname!=""])'
    , function() {
    var oname = $(this).attr('name');
    var newName = "random string";  // random string
    $(this).attr({"data-oname":oname,"name":newName,autocomplete:newName});
    // A random string should be set for name and autocomplete above.
}).on('blur', 'input[data-oname][data-oname!=""]', function() {
    var oname = $(this).attr('data-oname');
    $(this).attr({"name":oname}).removeAttr('data-oname');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    setTimeout(() => {
        $('input').attr("readonly", 'readonly');
        $('input').attr("onfocus", "this.removeAttribute('readonly')");
    }, 100);
    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the problem.

```js
$("body").on('focus',':input', function (e) {
    $(this).attr('autocomplete', 'off');
    $(this).attr('autocapitalize', 'off');
    $(this).attr('autocorrect', 'off');
    $(this).attr('spellcheck', 'false');
});
```

OR

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **autocomplete="new-password"** instead of **autocomplete="off"**. This is a newer, more specific value for the autocomplete attribute, which indicates that the field is for a new password, rather than just any input. This can help prevent the browser from auto-filling the field with old passwords.