# Chrome for Android showing Auto-fill even if autocomplete: off

Tags: jquery, forms, autocomplete, autofill

I have a form with 4 fields where the user is supposed to enter two cities (From and To) and two dates (outbound and return date).

I have `autocomplete:off`, which works fine among most of the browsers. However, for Chrome on Android I get the annoying Auto-fill that overlaps my own suggestion drop-down list.

[image: Screenshot showing the Autofill]

### Trials

I have tried every single one of the suggested solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31613047/5802289), including:

1) Putting a hidden field before my fields in the form. Even with the same name as the first real field:

```
<input type="text" style="display:none" name="same_name_as_1st_field"/>
```

2) Hidding a div, instead of the input tag directly:

```
<div style="display: none;">
    <input type="text" name="same_name_as_1st_field" />
</div>
```

3) Changing from `autocomplete="off"` to `autocomplete="false"`

4) Browser autofill in by readonly-mode.

```
<input type="password" readonly onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');"/>
```

5) `autocomplete="new-password"`

6) `<form autocomplete="off" role="presentation">`

7) With JQuery:

```
if ($.browser.webkit) {
    $('input[name="my_field_name"]').attr('autocomplete', 'off');
}
```

8) JQuery:

```
$(window).ready(function () {
    $('#my_id').val(' ').val('');
});
```

9) More complicated JQuery from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29337779/5802289):

> ```
> jQuery('body').on('mousedown keydown','[name="name"][autocomplete="off"],
> [name="email"][autocomplete="off"]',function(e){
>     e.stopImmediatePropagation();
>     if(typeof this.currentName =="undefined")
>         this.currentName=jQuery(this).attr('name');
>     jQuery(this).attr('name','');
> });
> jQuery('body').on('blur keyup','[autocomplete="off"]',function(e){
>     e.stopImmediatePropagation();
>     if(typeof this.currentName !="undefined")
>         jQuery(this).attr('name',this.currentName);
> });
> ```
>
> > Please notice that for Solution 1 and 2, I just took the cases where
> >     the input name is "name" and "email". For any other case where this
> >     attribute makes Chrome generate the dropdown you will have to add it
> >     in the selector for the mouse down event.

10) Own idea: I realized that by giving the field a default value, the auto-fill does not show up. Then, I tried giving a default value and clearing that value on focus with javascript...

```
<script>
    $('#id_From').focus(function() {
        this.value = "";
    });
</script>
```

And none works.

Any idea of how to solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill

Comment: That question is linked in my explanation. As I said, I tried every single suggestion there, and none is working.

Comment: My apologies. Did not see the link till just now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update (21-12-2017)

The old solution stopped working, so here is a new one.

The auto-fill is triggered with the following input tag:

```
<input type="search" name="To"  id="id_To" placeholder="a" class="autocomplete-city form-inner-field-city ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off" maxlength="50" required="">
```

Key here are the fields `name` and `id`, which were the ones modified with the old solution.
Apparently, Chrome identifies it as a field for Auto-fill. Thus, changing the name and id to something Chrome cannot identify seems to do the trick (for the moment).

For instance:

```
<input type="search" name="Dep"  id="id_Dep" placeholder="a" class="autocomplete-city form-inner-field-city ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off" maxlength="50" required="">
```

---

### OLD

Finally a solution that worked, from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25229226/5802289):

> It removes "name" and "id" attributes from elements and assigns them
>   back after 1ms. Put this in document get ready.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form[autocomplete="off"] input, input[autocomplete="off"]').each(function () {

                var input = this;
                var name = $(input).attr('name');
                var id = $(input).attr('id');

                $(input).removeAttr('name');
                $(input).removeAttr('id');

                setTimeout(function () {
                    $(input).attr('name', name);
                    $(input).attr('id', id);
                }, 1);
            });
});
```

Comment: It seems really gross that the only solution is to change the client side form name, therefore requiring the server side to be changed to look for the new nam. :(

Comment: I totally agree, Mark. If you ever find out another solution, please share it ;)