# primefacs 6.2 inputtext stop autofill

Tags: html, primefaces

[image]

i am trying to stop the autofill my input text

i used autocomplete="off" but still not work 1

```
<p:inputText id="username" style="color:black " value="#{userView.selectedUser.username}" required="true" autocomplete="off"
                            requiredMessage="#{msg['field.required.msg']}" label="#{msg['user.addEdit.user.name.title']}"
                            disabled="#{userView.selectedUser.username!=null}" />
```

Comment: It's your browser. There are many duplicates https://www.google.com/search?q=autocomplete%3D+off+not+working+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: So it works in PrimeFace 6.1?

Comment: Some lame workarounds: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31612867/autocomplete-off-not-working-in-chrome